# Coroutines interacting with threads

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine

C++ reference has the following statement on the coroutine page:

> Note that because the coroutine is fully suspended before entering
> `awaiter.await_suspend()`, that function is free to transfer the
> coroutine handle across threads, with no additional synchronization.

A suspended coroutine is just plain data, so that does make sense. However, even when transferring plain data between threads, you do need synchronization. So why don't you need it here?

Am I misinterpreting this statement? Is there some implied memory barrier at work here?

Comment: Note that _"with no **additional** synchronization"_. It does not mean that there is no synchronization.

Comment: @DanielLangr Is that what they are trying to say? If you are synchronizing your state, there are no extra hoops to jump through to move your coroutines across threads?

Comment: I am not a coroutine expert, but I guess they are trying to say that you don't need to care about any explicit synchronization. It should be therefore safe to write data (say of non-atomic `int` type) before suspension and read it after resumption in another thread. And some internal mechanism needs to synchronize such read and write. Please, correct me anyone, if I am wrong.

Comment: It's [Inter-thread happens-before](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Inter-thread_happens-before). Passing the data to `std::thread::thread` is *synchronizes-with* the new thread starting, and the new thread starting is *sequenced-before* any operations on it

Comment: @Caleth If you are starting a new thread, sure. I was thinking more of a threadpool. But I guess, then there will be some memory barriers on the threadpool side.

Comment: @ŠimonTóth you only need additional synchronization if there is a data race. In this case the standard is saying "Hey as long as you don't touch the `resume` member of the coroutine handle until you get to the other thread, *this must be thread safe*. So it's actually a guarantee from the standard that this *isn't* a data race.

Comment: @Mgetz That's a bit wishy-washy. If you are passing a coroutine around threads, then there needs to be a memory barrier somewhere, or somehow the synchronization must be implied for some other reason that I'm currently not getting. Somehow the data in the coroutine need to be made visible to the new thread. The case when a new thread is create has been already mentioned and that one I get, but I still don't understand what happens when you move to an existing thread. If there is a memory barrier generated by the compiler, I want to know if it's there always, or if there is some special logic.

Comment: @ŠimonTóth why? A data race only occurs if you're accessing the data from two threads at once. If you're not (and you're not), then it's not a data race. It's that simple. Is it possible the implementation could force a barrier to ensure the coroutine is visible to the other CPU? Yes! But the standard *cannot and should not* dictate that because that's an implementation detail based on the specific architecture and cache coherency. Not a standard issue. Regardless from a *language* perspective, it's safe and data race free. I realize that's not what you were looking for.

Comment: @Mgetz The C++ memory model was introduced to dictate the very thing you are claiming it cannot and should not dictate. It also defines what is a data race. You might want to read it before commenting: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model

Comment: @ŠimonTóth I have, the memory model only dictates what is and isn't a data race and gives methods for eliminating them. It does not place requirements on the use of those tools in the implementation. `std::atomic` can and *is* optimized away on x86 for multiple data types because the memory model of x86 processors does not require the `lock` prefix.

Comment: @Mgetz Then you would know that everything except from: a) the two evaluations are happening on the same thread, b) they are atomic, or c) they are explicitly sequenced is a data race. So since in this case, since a) and b) are not applicable, they should be explicitly sequenced, hence my question.

Comment: The function that transfers the coroutine handle across threads has to do so in a thread-safe manner. If the implementation decides to take it away from one thread and give it to another then there must be some sort of message queue or other implementation-defined synchronization. And if the implementation decides not to pass anything across threads then there is no need for synchronization. The text is telling you that you don't need to guard against the implementation passing your coroutine to another thread because only one thread at a time will run the coroutine.

Comment: @nwp This sounds like a reasonable interpretation. Can you make it into an answer?

Comment: Uh ... feel free to copy/paste/modify it yourself if it actually answers your question.

Comment: I wrote that bit on cppreference, and I did it with https://lewissbaker.github.io/2017/11/17/understanding-operator-co-await#synchronisation-free-async-code in mind